# Cannot set StorageEngineMode property because Analysis Services is in Tabular mode

Tags: sql-server, ssas, data-analysis

I am doing a Analysis Multidimension project. I try to process a dimension but VS return this error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFhIk.png)

I have try to:

- reinstall SQL Server and choose Multidimensional and Data Mining in Analysis Services Configuration.
- Change deploymode to 0 in MAS14.MSSQLSERVER/OLAP/Config/msmdsrv.ini

I'm sure that my analysis service is in mutidimension mode.

[My Analysis Service Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoDbZ.png)

I wonder if how i solve this problem.